# SQLAlchemy events

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь использовать события SQLAlchemy.
Задача - отследить инсерт, апдейт или делит в любой из моделей, получив при этом саму модель, данные, которые обновились, id записи в таблице, и желательно, "старые данные".

Ситуация следующая:

при инсерте принт такой:

```
None was insered
leed was updated
```

при апдейте:

```
None was updated
```

при делите:

```
None was deleted
```

Что не так делаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста. кто знает.

**"""UPDATE"""**

Проблема заключалась в том, что instance - это `__repr__` модели, а возвращало None по причине, что этих данных попросту не было.

Не кажется правильным получать `__tablename__` из `mapper`, и не совсем понятно, как быть, если я далеко не всегда в `__repr__` вывожу `id`

```
from ._base import db
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError, InterfaceError
from flask import flash
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.event import listen

from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import MapperExtension

class BaseExtension(MapperExtension):

    def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        print(str(mapper).split('|')[1])
        print(str(instance) + ' was insered')

    def before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        print(str(mapper).split('|')[1])
        print(str(instance) + ' was updated')

    def before_delete(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        print(str(mapper).split('|')[1])
        print(str(instance) + ' was deleted')



class Base(db.Model):

    __abstract__ = True
    __mapper_args__ = { 'extension': BaseExtension() }

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())

    @classmethod
    def create(cls,**kwargs):
        c = cls(**kwargs)
        db.session.add(c)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created successfully!', 'success')
        except IntegrityError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created failed!' + u' IntegrityError', 'error')
            print('IntegrityError')
        except InterfaceError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created failed!' + u' InterfaceError', 'error')
            print('InterfaceError')
        return c
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модель получить удалось проще, чем я думал, а именно:

```
instance.__class__.__name__
```

Получить старые данные не удалось, да и в моём частном случае, не особенно важно.
Но текущую дату удалось получить, путём изменения `__repr__` у базовой модели. Пришлось создать генератор словаря, с обработкой исключений в ключах.

Возможно так делать не верно, но, лучшего способа я не нашёл.

```
    def __repr__(self):
        mapper = inspect(self).mapper

        object_data = {col.key: getattr(self, col.key) if not col.key == 'created_at' and not col.key == 'password' and not col.key == 'modified_at' else None for col in mapper.column_attrs}

        return "{0}".format(object_data)
```